# Creating a sample app with Ogre

Tags: iphone, ogre

I installed the OgreSDK for iOS. I Installed Cmake, I downloaded the Ogre SDK, and I downloaded the iPhone dependencies.

I have placed the iPhone dependencies in the OgreSDK. Then I tried to run ogre.Xcodeproject, but I got the following error: `some config files are missing`. I have added the files in the bin, then it ran successfully. I installed the Ogre template for XCode.

I started of creating my first application, but when I try to run, I get an
error like `ogreCamera.h not found`.

I have checked in the header search path, whether it contains the root of OgreSDK. It is correct, and I have added them manually.

Then I got this error ld: `library not found for -lOIS`
`Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1`

Please help me, I have been struggling with this for one day.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tutorial maybe useful to you
    http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Compile+and+run+OgreOde+on+iPhone 
    http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/ogreOnIphoneFast
    http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Ogre+iPhone

Good Luck